# How do we know when to call "value" as opposed to "value()"?

Tags: javascript

Have a look at the last two answers.

How can we ***determine*** without looking into any documentation that sliderinput.value is the right answer, and not sliderinput.value()?

Im coming from Java. Im used to call accessor methods.

What is "value" as opposed to "value()"?
What is sliderinput if not an object?

[image]

Comment: `value` is a property whilst `value()` is a call to a method/function

Comment: you have to learn these things to know what something returns (`getElementById`) and what properties and functions are available. the best way is to test it yourself.

Comment: Without looking at the documentation? You can log the `sliderinput` to the console and inspect what properties and methods it has.

Comment: value is a document's property , value() is a jquery method

Answer (score 0):

You can determine this by checking if `value` is a function:

```
typeof sliderinput.value === "function"
```

Javascript usually doesn't use getter functions like `value()`. If you want to use getters you can use the `get` syntax to create a getter function that can be called using normal property syntax. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get

In the context of this quiz you've posted, I suppose they just want you to know from the top of your head that value is a property in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the attribute **value** of **sliderinput** is a string, so the options with parenthesis () are not valid and will throw an error. You could do that only if **value** were a *function type variable*, which is not.

Edit: as other members pointed out, you can use **typeof** to check the variable type; in this case it will be *"string"*

Answer (score 0):

> How can we determine without looking into any documentation that sliderinput.value is the right answer, and not sliderinput.value()?

You can try it and see.

You can test its type (with the `typeof` operator) to see if it is a function or something else.

… but *reading the documentation*, despite you dismissing it, is the correct approach.

Comment: Okey, I will rephrase. How can I determine that I must use value (property) instead of value() (method) without having access to any documentation nor a browser or IDE. I guess i cant? My intepretation of the quiz question was that I could determine this without being able to test, try or check anything.. just by looking at the code..

Comment: @Slamdunk — You can't. The quiz appears to be trying to test your memorised knowledge of a standard API.